# What is the value to Variable when query results nothing in CAML

Tags: 2013, list, caml

What is the Value of $spQuery when no items were returned from the filter in the query given below:

I am trying to add a conditional statement at end of this script.

```
if ($spQuery -eq $null){ Write-host " No results were found"}  
    $list = $web.Lists["SharePoint Site Request"]

    $spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery

    $spQuery.RowLimit = 2000
    $caml = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Choice'>Approved/Pending</Value></Eq>
       </Where>
       <OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>" 
    $spQuery.Query = $caml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean that result item collection is empty:

```
$itemsCollection = $list.GetItems($spQuery)
if($itemsCollection.Count -eq 0)
{
 Write-host " No results were found"
}
```